# Sort file names (numbered) in dired

Tags: dired, sorting

When Dired sorts files by name, it sorts in alphabetical order. That's fine with letters; however, when the file names start with numbers, it would be better to sort in numerical value.

Example:

This is how dired sorts my files:

10
11
12
13
...
1
21
22
23
...
2
31

I want 1 2 3 4 … 9 10 11 …

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's my config:

```
(setq dired-listing-switches "-laGh1v --group-directories-first")
```

The relevant part is `-1v`.

Answer (score 5):

Besides @abo-abo answer, I just want to quote the documentation:

> `dired-listing-switches` is a variable defined in `dired.el'. Its value
>   is "-Al --si --time-style long-iso"
>
> Documentation: Switches passed to `ls` for Dired.  MUST contain the
>   `l` option. May contain all other options that don't contradict `-l`;
>   may contain even `F`, `b`, `i` and `s`.  See also the variable
>   `dired-ls-F-marks-symlinks` concerning the `F` switch. On systems such
>   as MS-DOS and MS-Windows, which use `ls` emulation in Lisp, some of
>   the `ls` switches are not supported; see the doc string of
>   `insert-directory` in `ls-lisp.el` for more details.

Basically, you can customize the switches you want dired to use when calling `ls`

Answer (score 3):

The given answers are better for this precise problem because they hook directly into the behavior of Dired. However for generality's sake I want to mention the `sort-numeric-fields` command, which is specifically for sorting numbers by magnitude rather than lexicographically.

> `(sort-numeric-fields FIELD BEG END)`
>
> Sort lines in region numerically by the `ARG`th field of each line. Fields are separated by whitespace and numbered from 1 up. Specified field must contain a number in each line of the region, which may begin with "0x" or "0" for hexadecimal and octal values. Otherwise, the number is interpreted according to `sort-numeric-base`. With a negative arg, sorts by the `ARG`th field counted from the right. Called from a program, there are three arguments: `FIELD`, `BEG` and `END`.  `BEG` and `END` specify region to sort.